# Visualizing UIStackView?

Tags: ios, uistackview

The question is quite simple - I really like to use UIStackView to organize UI. However, I could not see the UIStackView boundary in the test app. When the UI elements are not expected, I need to spend so much time to debug. Searching on the web, I could not find a way to show the boundaries of the UIStackView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried clicking on the **Debug View Hierarchy** button in the debug bar?

[image]

Please refer to this (from Apple): [Specialized Debugging Workflows](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2).

Comment: How am I just discovering this tool?!?!?!

Answer (score 2):

I would use Xcode's “Debug View Hierarchy” support, as ferunandu's answer shows. This is the easiest way since `UIStackView` is implemented specifically **not** to render any graphics itself (by using a `CATransformLayer` as its layer).

But there is way to see the “boundary” of a stack view in place at runtime. Just add another view (anywhere in the view hierarchy), and constrain it to have the same frame as the stack view. You could do this in the storyboard or in code. Here's how you could do it in code:

```
extension UIStackView {

    func showBoundary() {
        let boundary = UIView()
        boundary.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.5, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
        boundary.layer.borderWidth = 1
        boundary.backgroundColor = nil
        boundary.frame = self.bounds
        boundary.autoresizingMask = [ .FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight ]

        addSubview(boundary) // Note: **not** addArrangedSubview!
    }

}
```

Then call `stackView.showBoundary()` on your stack view.

Comment: I always wondered why you couldn't do things to the stack view's layer. So it's because it's a transform layer! Why did Apple do that? New in iOS 14, it will become a normal CALayer, so maybe Apple has relented or repented...

Comment: I assume it was cheaper because the system never allocates a backing store for a `CATransformLayer`. But they probably got tired of bug reports about backgroundColor, border, etc not working on stacks.